# Does iOS7 Multipeer Connectivity support classic bluetooth or BLE 4.0?

Tags: objective-c, ios7, core-bluetooth, multipeer-connectivity

Can someone clarify: does the iOS7 Multipeer Connectivity support classic bluetooth or BLE 4.0 ?

Similarly, does the Core Bluetooth (CB) framework support classic bluetooth or BLE 4.0 ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the [Multipeer Connectivity Framework](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/MultipeerConnectivity/Reference/MultipeerConnectivityFramework/Introduction/Introduction.html) overview

> discovering services provided by nearby iOS devices using
>   infrastructure Wi-Fi networks, peer-to-peer Wi-Fi, and Bluetooth
>   personal area networks

PAN is not a real option with BLE due to the low bandwidth it provides, therefore, MC works only on classic Bluetooth.

Core Bluetooth is exclusively for BLE. Classic Bluetooth cannot be used directly, only through the External Accessory Framework.